# What are the benefits of grpc with a rest as a gateway?

Tags: rest, grpc

What are the benefits of grpc with rest as a gateway like described here --> https://grpc.io/blog/coreos ?

Since grpc-web is not mature enough yet (like described here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/comparison?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and it is important to interact with Browsers, too, i could just use a REST API to solve everything.

Comment: https://grpc.io/blog/coreos seems to be broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST and gRPC are both tools that fit different use cases. If you have a large enough project that would benefit from a microservice architecture, gRPC provides type safe inter-service communication, performance gains, and automatic server and client stub generation. Imagine never having to implement a HTTP client stub again, for me, that’s the best argument to use gRPC. For REST, there’s code generation tools like Swagger but they’re cumbersome and half of the spec file ends up being HTTP bloat, when I simply just want to call a function on a server. Of course, with gRPC you still need to implement a REST API assuming you need to support browser based clients—but this REST api will be fairly simple and will only have the concern of delegating to the correct gRPC microservices.